# Delphi XE10.2 Import WSDL error TRIDIUM / NIAGARA

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a solution to browse the database of Niagara database from a Delphi client application and I'm trying to find a way to access the database.
I appears oBix and SOAP is available. (I know abs. nothing about oBix!)

I'm completely new to this Niagara platform and to SOAP.

I'm trying to use SOAP and use Delphi WSDL import, but it fails with an error about invalid characters in line 23.

This is what I try to import.
https://obix.tridium.com/obix/wsdl

Does anyone have a clue on why it fails or what am I doing wrong?

I tried another import http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL - that works fine.

Comment: The first link you supplied requires a login. Can you provide the login details, or a link to where they might be obtained?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
https://obix.tridium.com/obix/
"DemoUser" + "Tr1diumD3mo"

Comment: The URL does not support authentication via a direct HTTP request with authentication in the headers, which is what the Delphi WSDL import is attempting to do. You'll need to log in to that site manually (i.e. via a browser), save the WSDL to a file, and import it from the file.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that makes good sense, I didn't think about that, I have downloaded the two files and after a merge of the WSDL and WSD I could import it from file.